# UITextField with rounded corners - setting layer in run time attributes in IB don't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextfield, ios7.1

I am trying to create a rounded corners UITextField by modifying the runtime attributes in Interface Builder.

Here is what I want it to look like:

[image: rounded corners text field]

Here is what I'm doing:

[image: runtime attribute modification]

and here is the undesired result:

[image]

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: always UItextfield shows in rounded corners na, then y u need to change

Comment: Does not show round corners in iOS7 plus i need to modify the height

Comment: @MichalShatz:create textfield with border style none. Then set the background image as like what you want..

Comment: @TamilKing I could do that sure but I am trying to figure out why drawing does not work before I hack around this

Comment: @it works or u need any changes

Comment: //To make the border look very close to a UITextField
[urtextfiledname.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor]];
[urtextfiledname.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];

//The rounded corner part, where you specify your view's corner radius:
urtextfiledname.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
urtextfiledname.clipsToBounds = YES;

Comment: Perhaps it works in code. Did not work in interface builder.

Answer (score 2):

use `border style` is `plain it automatically change the custom heights

[image]

also set the corner radius and `background color` of your `textfield`

[image]

if you need to change the Alpha value

[image]

Comment: set the layer of corner radius and mask bounds it takes you onwards ur work

Comment: This resulted in an invisible order despite specifying grey border color in layout in the runtime attributes. So this did not work but I see 2 up votes so I wonder if I am missing anything?

Comment: @MichalShatz  ya its showing the translucent background of uitextfield, u need to change the background color of the text filed, then it will visible in the view controller

Comment: But I want the translucent background IO just want to modify the borders.

Comment: change the alpha value between 0 to 1

Comment: It is 1. Can you upload an image of the result pleas?

Comment: @MichalShatz u see the difference the difference between 2 textfields

Comment: Yes. I see this would work for the text field but not for the borders which is not what I need. I need to create a rounded rect frame. Close enough but not what I need :)

Comment: @just wait u need the translucent border of the uitext field na, i post the another one answer

Answer (score 1):

The 'border' is explicitly drawn based on the 'border style' so doesn't change based on the layer properties and just gets clipped as you show. You could try setting layer.borderColor to the colour you want and layer.borderWidth to the width required and set the 'border style' to none. (dotted rectangle). This should add a layer border of the colour and width provided that follows the corner radius set. Any reason the rounded corner border style isn't acceptable?

Answer (score -1):

You have to add `QuartzCore` framework in you project , if that didn't work try adding it manually in your code.

```
textfield.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
textfield.layer.masksToBounds = true;
```

Hope this help

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
  yourTextField.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
  yourTextField.clipsToBounds = YES;
  yourTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
```